# Export variable with trailing spaces and quotes

Tags: sas

How can I export a character variable WITH trailing spaces and quotes?

eg:

```
data x;
format x $quote17.;
x='ruby';
put x=;
run;

(log extract)
x="ruby"
```

What is the most efficient way to get the following result?

```
x="ruby             "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a way..

```
data x;
format x $19.;
x='ruby';
x=quote(subpad(x,1,17));
put x=;
run;
```

not sure if this is the most efficient though!

Comment: Should W always be VLENGTH+2 or is it arbitrary as suggested by your examples? Why do you need to quoted blanks?

Comment: I was writing some text file outputs that had to match another set of outputs exactly as a testing requirement. No relation to vlength..

Answer (score 1):

```
data x;
  Format x $17. q$1.;
  x='Ruby';
  q='"';
  qxq=cat(q,x,q);
  Put qxq=;
run;
```